# Django 1.8.3 Running test fails on database creation

Tags: python, django, database, testing, django-1.8

I am trying to run "manage.py test" but i get the following error message:

```
(env)user@comp:~/Documents/repo/cloud/webapp$ python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 210, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 166, in setup_databases
    **kwargs
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 370, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 368, in create_test_db
    test_flush=not keepdb,
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 179, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 317, in sync_apps
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist
```

I have a custom user model. I have read that this problem occurs because Django migrates your app before it migrates auth which causes an error because the custom user model references the auth.user model. However i didn't find a fix for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a model in an app without migrations, with a foreign key to `auth.User`. As noted in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#dependencies):

> Be aware, however, that unmigrated apps cannot depend on migrated apps, by the very nature of not having migrations. This means that it is not generally possible to have an unmigrated app have a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField to a migrated app; some cases may work, but it will eventually fail.

You have to add migrations for the app with a foreign key to your user model.

Comment: Apparently i forgot about two apps in my project that i didn't migrate and that was the reason for the failure. Thing is Django doesn't migrate those apps when you run manage.py migrate, so i had to do that manually. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the below commands first:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
$ python manage.py syncdb
```

If you make any changes to your model definitions in `models.py` you have to run SQL migration queries to move your database to your new model.